# Как установить куки во время авторизации?

Tags: php, cookie

У меня есть форма авторизации, на страничке в самом начале выводится хедер, стандартный, как на всех остальных страницах. В хедер подключается файл конфига, сео и проверка на наличие этих кук, что не даёт сделать setcookie на странице авторизации под формой. Как устанавливать куки если перед этим нужно вывести хедер и кучу другой информации?

Вот страница логина:

```
<?php 
require_once "blocks/header.php"; 
?>

<div style="padding-bottom: 10px;"><h1>Вход</h1></div>

<div class="addform"> 

    <form method="POST" action="login.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        <span class="input-group-prepend">Логин</span> 
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="login" required>

        <span class="input-group-prepend">Пароль</span> 
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="password" required>

        <input type="hidden" id="g-recaptcha-response" name="g-recaptcha-response" />

        <span class="note">Protected by Google captcha</br></span>

        </br><span class="input-group-prepend"><input name='remember' type='checkbox' value="1"> Запомнить меня</br></span>
        </br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Войти" class="btn btn-success">

    </form>

</div>


<?

if ($_SESSION['login'] == true) {

    echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="0; URL=profile.php">';
    exit;

} else {
    
/*КЛЮЧИ*/
define('SITE_KEY', '..........');
define('SECRET_KEY', '.............');

/*ОБРАБОТКА ЗАПРОСА*/
if($_POST){
    /*СОЗДАЕМ ФУНКЦИЮ КОТОРАЯ ДЕЛАЕТ ЗАПРОС НА GOOGLE СЕРВИС*/
    function getCaptcha($SecretKey) {
        $Response = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=".SECRET_KEY."&response={$SecretKey}");
        $Return = json_decode($Response);
        return $Return;
    }
    
    /*ПРОИЗВОДИМ ЗАПРОС НА GOOGLE СЕРВИС И ЗАПИСЫВАЕМ ОТВЕТ*/
    $Return = getCaptcha($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']);
    /*ВЫВОДИМ НА ЭКРАН ПОЛУЧЕННЫЙ ОТВЕТ*/
    //var_dump($Return);
    
    /*ЕСЛИ ЗАПРОС УДАЧНО ОТПРАВЛЕН И ЗНАЧЕНИЕ score БОЛЬШЕ 0,5 ВЫПОЛНЯЕМ КОД*/
    if($Return->success == true && $Return->score > 0.5){
        //echo "Succes!";

    $login = $_POST['login'];
    $password = md5($_POST['password']);


    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE login='$login'";
    if($result = $conn->query($sql)){
    
        foreach($result as $row){
            $logindb = $row["login"] . $row["password"];
        }

        $result->free();
    
    } else{
        echo "Ошибка: " . $conn->error;
    }


    if ($logindb == $login . $password && $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
        echo "</br>Входим...</br>";

        session_start(); 

        // инициализируем переменные сессии
        $_SESSION['login'] = $login;
        $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

        //Проверяем, что была нажата галочка 'Запомнить меня':
        if ( !empty($_REQUEST['remember']) and $_REQUEST['remember'] == 1 ) {
            //Сформируем случайную строку для куки:
            $qkey = uniqid();
            //Пишем куки (имя куки, значение, время жизни - сейчас+месяц)
            setcookie('login', $login, time()+60*60*24*30); //логин
            setcookie('key', $qkey, time()+60*60*24*30); //случайная строка

        // добавляем qkey
        $sql = "UPDATE users SET qkey = '$qkey' WHERE login='$login'";
        if($conn->query($sql)){ } else { echo "Ошибка" . $conn->error; }
        }

        // обновляем дату входа
        $sql = "UPDATE users SET visit = '$date' WHERE login='$login'";
        if($conn->query($sql)){ } else { echo "Ошибка" . $conn->error; }

        // переходим в профиль
        echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="0; URL=profile.php">';

    } else if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')  {
        echo "</br>Что-то не так.";
        sleep(1);
    } 
    }
    else {
        echo "You are Robot";
        sleep(2);
    }
}

}

?>

<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=<?php echo SITE_KEY?>"></script>
    <script>
        grecaptcha.ready(function() {
            grecaptcha.execute('<?php echo SITE_KEY;?>', {action: 'homepage'}).then(function(token) {
                //console.log(token);
                document.getElementById('g-recaptcha-response').value=token;
            });
        });
</script>

<?php require_once "blocks/footer.php"; ?>
```

Вот начало хедера:

```
<?php 
session_cache_limiter('private_no_expire'); // works
header('Last-Modified: ' . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . ' GMT');
header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: no-cache');
header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); 

include "config.php";// подключение к базе
include "seo.php"; //SEO

if ( !empty($_COOKIE['login']) and !empty($_COOKIE['key']) ) {
    //Пишем логин и ключ из КУК в переменные (для удобства работы):
    //echo 'yes';
    $loginq = $_COOKIE['login']; 
    $keyq = $_COOKIE['key'];
        //определение данных залогиненого из бд
        $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);
        if (!$conn) {
        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
        }
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE login='$loginq'";
        if($result = $conn->query($sql)){ foreach($result as $row){ 
        $dbkeys = $row["login"] . $row["qkey"]; 
        } $result->free(); }
        //проверяем совпадение
        if ($dbkeys == $loginq . $keyq) {
            session_start(); 
            //Пишем в сессию логин и id пользователя (их мы берем из переменной $user!):
            $_SESSION['login'] = $loginq;

        } else{
        session_start();// запускаем сессию
        }  
}
```

.............

Ошибка: Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent

Answer (score 0):

header.php:

```
<?php 
session_cache_limiter('private_no_expire'); // works
header('Last-Modified: ' . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . ' GMT');
header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: no-cache');
header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); 

//Это единственное место где нужно вызывать данную команду, больше нигде не нужно, если у вас подключен хидер"
session_start(); 
.....
```

p.s. Далее по коду:

```
$_COOKIE['login'];
```

Никогда, НИКОГДА, не делайте так. нельзя в куках хранить логин и пароль. в сессии - пожалуйста, в куках - никогда.

Передали на сервер данные авторизации, проверили все, и сохранили в массив $_SESSION необходимые вам данные.

Ну и судя по всему вы путаете куки и сессии, это разные вещи...

```
 $loginq = $_COOKIE['login']; 
 $_SESSION['login'] = $loginq;
```

Вот примерный код который вам нужно реализовать:

```
<?php
  session_start();
  if(!isset($_SESSION['userid']) && !isset($_POST['login'])){
    // Здесь пользователь не авторизован и не прислал логин
  } elseif(!isset($_SESSION['userid']) && (
    isset($_POST['login']) || isset[$_COOKIE[{LongTimeAuthData}]])){
    //Пользователь всё еще не авторизован, но хочет это сделать
    //нужно проверить что пользователь существует в БД и положить его идентификатор в $_SESSION['userid']
    //создать куку с нужными переменными для дительного хранения сесси, и возобновления ее
  } elseif(isset($_SESSION['userid'])){
    //пользователь авторизован, его id => $_SESSION['userid']
  }
```

Обратите внимание в примере - заголовочный файл(т.е. файл который подключается во все скрипты где нужно знать авторизован пользователь или нет)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Но я в куках храню только логин, без пароля. Вторая кука - это рандомный ключ, который генерируется при каждой авторизации и заносится в базу и потом в хедере проверяется совпадение. Если совпало, значит логин действительный. Даже яндекс метрика мой логин в куках хранит). Вопрос не в этом, вопрос в том, как послать куки в середине кода? Я же не могу послать в куки логин не определив его, а это вызывает ошибку Cannot modify header information

Comment: Ответ в том что вам не нужно посылать куки в середине кода, при работе через сессию все данные хранятся на сервере, и могут быть изменены в любое время выполнения скрипта. Но если очень хочется помучатся и отправлять данные заголовка посередине скрипта - вам нужен буферизированный вывод https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.ob-start.php.

Comment: спасибо буду изучать, но  даже при выходе из профиля нужно сначала сделать проверку, а для этого подключиться к базе и тд, например: if(isset($_GET['exit'])), а только потом посылать куки, чтобы они уничтожили текущие setcookie('login', '', time()); //удаляем логин . Я просто не очень понимаю как этот механизм работает. в самом верху можно отправить только какие-то статичные данные, без всяких проверок, а что если нужно их сделать?

Comment: Вот поэтому как пример работы с авторизацией, я вам и привел работу через сессию, для выхода достаточно сделать так `unset($_SESSION['userid'])` и нет необходимости проверять что либо в БД, пользователь не может повлиять на чужую сессию, только на свою. После вызова команды `session_start()` - вам доступен массив `$_SESSION` и в нем данные хранятся от запроса к запросу(у каждого пользователя свои данные), нет необходимости ничего руками сохранять в куки или куда бы то нибыло еще, хранение в куках нужно только для длительной(после закрытия браузера) паузы(и то это поведение можно изменить).

Comment: мне как раз это и нужно, чтобы после закрытия браузера не нужно было авторизовываться ещё раз

Comment: Дополнил пример.